# How to make HTTPPost Request with body in C#

Tags: c#, post, http-headers, http-post, httprequest

So I was trying to use an API Rest where I get information using a Post request, I have done this previously and it works fine, but this time I also have to use code in the body and a key.

I have seen other questions about how to implement Post requests in C#, but all of them were trying to post data...

In Postman this is what I have:

Base URL: xxxx

Endpoint: /yyyy

-KEY-

-KeyValue-

and in the body:

```
fields name, summary, url, platforms;
limit 15;
where rating_count > 200 & version_parent = null;
sort rating desc;
```

I already know how to store the information that the API Rest gives back, but I don't know how to use the key nor the body code in C#.

And that is all, thank you for your time, I hope everyone has a good day.

EDIT: I have tried to make the HTTP request using GET instead of POST using postman and it works fine, though in the documentation of the API says that you are supposed to use POST, still I don't know how to implement it in C#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVC you can get data from body request:

```
public YyyyController: Controller
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [Route(""), HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromUri] string key, [FromBody] string requestBody){}

}
```

It works if you send POST request like this:

```
http://url.com/yyyy?key=key_value
Any text for parametrs requestBody
```